# Asynchronous push using on demand Renderer not working on AIX

Tags: java, icefaces-1.8

I am using the  com.icesoft.faces.async.render.RenderManager for asynchronous push to ice-faces front-end;

renderManager.getOnDemandRenderer(identifier).requestRender();
Here identifiers is a key which is used in a  ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

This works well in windows environment ( using IBM JDK as well Oracle JRocket ) , but the same doesn't work in AIX environemnt.
Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is resolved, It was a coding issue, and not a issue on rendering.